# PHP require_once oddly not working?

Tags: php, wordpress, include, require

I'm trying to include a file in a page. The file is located in a folder called phpThumb which is placed inside my wordpress theme directory.
This is how I tried to include the file"

`<?php require_once(get_bloginfo('template_url')."/phpThumb/phpThumb.config.php"); ?>`

For some reason, this doesn't work.
I did check and `get_bloginfo()` **returns** a value and does not **echo** a value.
I triple checked the code for validity and it's all fine IMO...

What could possibly be wrong?

P.S ; It worked using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` but the output of it is dependent on the current page (correct me if I'm wrong) so it's not as efficient for me.

Comment: `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is not dependent on the current page/file.

Comment: require would expect a dir not a url

Comment: it is almost certainly the path to the php file. Try using `getcwd() `instead of `get_bloginfo('template_url')`

Comment: @ColeJohnson What else could you possible need? This line is placed in the head.php file - there's nothing else to it... Proof is popnoodles easily solved it :) 

Shredder Thanks for pointing that out.

eskimo - Thanks for the alternative!

Comment: i don't get why 2 people -1'd this. @ColeJohnson all the required code was supplied.

Comment: @popnoodles We don't have `get_bloginfo`.

Comment: @ColeJohnson `get_bloginfo()` is a built-in wordpress function... http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[require_once](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php) expects a **file in a directory** not a url.

Replace `get_bloginfo('template_url')` with the Wordpress function [`get_template_directory()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory).

```
<?php require_once(get_template_directory()."/phpThumb/phpThumb.config.php"); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you! That was it! I completely forgot to check what the function actually receives as a parameter. :D

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to require, not include.  If you want to include do this:
`<?php
include("page");
?>`

Comment: Thanks but that's not the problem. `include` and `require` functions are the same except for their error handling : http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp

Comment: they aren't the same, but in this case it's a config file `require_once` is the right one to use. FYI w3schools provides bad info. http://w3fools.com/

Comment: Oh is it! I was actually using them a lot... just because I thought they were affiliated with w3c... which appears to be utter BS... good to know! better than never. Thanks once again @popnoodles :P

Answer (score 1):

`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is not dependent on the current page/file. It will give you the system file path to your web root folder. `require_once` expects a system file path. So if your `phpThumb.config.php` is sitting at `/dir1/dir2/phpThumb/phpThumb.config.php` from your web root. You would do this

```
require_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/dir1/dir2/phpThumb/phpThumb.config.php');
```

Check the output of `get_bloginfo('template_url')."/phpThumb/phpThumb.config.php"` and compare it to the above.